# Trying to make a repeater function using only higher order functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that accepts another function and outputs that function repeatedly by only using function expressions/applications.

So far I have a function `twice` which accepts another function as an argument and returns `func(func(x))`:

```
function twice(func) {
    function x(x) {
        return func(func(x));
    } 
    return x;
}
```

I'm trying to make a `repeater` function such that `const thrice = repeater(twice)` returns `func(func(func(x)))`, and `const fourtimes = repeater(thrice)` etc. but i'm confused as to how to do this. Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using your current structure thats impossible as `twice` does not expose a reference to `func`, thus `repeater` cannot call it.

The only solution I could think of would be to leak `func` from the inside through a (hidden) property:

```js
  const r = Symbol();
   
const repeater = f => Object.assign(
  v => f[r] ? f(f[r](v)): f(v),
  { [r]: f[r] || f }
);

const addThree = repeater(repeater(repeater(n => n + 1)));

console.log(addThree(10));
```

Comment: Any reason for not using snippets?

Comment: @adiga yup, don't work on mobile and I'm too lazy to copy the <snippet> tags manually.

Comment: @JonasWilms you can "request desktop website" in many mobile browsers (safari, chrome)...is that option available to you?

Comment: Yes, it's what I do when I don't have WiFi or can't use my laptop.

Comment: @JackBashford honestly it's not worth the effort. It's also fun that the only working answer of two questions yet did not recieve any upvote

Answer (score 0):

You should two base cases (`if n == 0 => exit`, `if n == 1 => return f(x)`), where `n` is an additional parameter that specifies how many times the function should repeat with the arguments `args`:

```js
function repeater(func, x, n) {
  if (n == 0) return;
  if (n == 1) return func(x);
  else {
    return func(repeater(func, x, --n));
  }
}

let sqr = n => n * n;

console.log(repeater(sqr, 2, 3));
```

Comment: Thats not exactly what the OP is looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you look for something like this?

```
function chain(f, g) {
    return function (x) {
        return f(g(x));
    }
}

function ntimes(f, n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return function (x) { return x }
    } else {
        return chain(f, ntimes(f, n-1));
    }
}
```

This will make a new function which repeats the original function `f` `n` times.